# call static block in view.phtml insted of phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, product-view, phtml

we are displaying text field in view page to check COD availability.

[image]

**view.phtml**

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('checkdelivery/checkdelivery.phtml')->toHtml();
```

in `view.phtml` we are calling below file . but **i want to call static block identifier**  [identifier code - check] instead of below file.

template/checkdelivery/checkdelivery.phtml

```
<div class="block block-list block-check-delivery">
    <div class="block-title">
        <?php $blockLabel = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/block_title'); ?>
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__($blockLabel) ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content" >        
        <br>
            <input name="zipcode" size="17" type="text" id="zipcode" value="<?php echo Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('zip'); ?>" maxlength="10" class="input-text" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Enter ZIP Code'); ?>"/>
            <button type="button" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check" ><span><?php echo $this->__('Check'); ?></span></button>
            <div id="delivery-message"></div>
            <?php $defaultHtml = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/default_html'); ?>
            <div id="delivery-html"><?php if(Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('message')){
    echo Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('message');
}
else{
    $defaultHtml; } ?></div>

        <br>        
    </div>

</div>

<script>
    Event.observe('zip-check', 'click', function(event){
        new Ajax.Request("<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkdelivery/index/index') ?>", {
            method: "get",
            parameters: {zipcode : $('zipcode').value },
            onSuccess: function(transport) {
                 var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                 $('delivery-message').update(json.message);                 
                 $('delivery-message').setStyle({ color: json.color});
                 $('delivery-html').update(json.html);  
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

static block code :

```
<p>{{block type ="core/template" template = "checkdelivery/checkdelivery.phtml"}}</p>
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use the below code:

in .phtml file :

```
<?php
  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); 
?>
```

sample :

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('home')->toHtml(); ?>
```

in static block / cms page :

`{{block type="core/template" template="checkdelivery/checkdelivery.phtml"}}`

Comment: its not displaying textfield now. i updated the static block code in question.

Comment: did you refresh you cache?

Comment: yes deleted cache folder, also removed browser cache.

Comment: `{{block type ="core/template" template="checkdelivery/checkdelivery.phtml" }}` remove space and check the `system->permission ->block` it is listed (core/template)?

Comment: createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block') instead of ->createBlock('cms/block') wordked for me :) Thanks for this tip!

Answer (score 3):

If you have created CMS block named 'block_identifier' from admin panel. Then following will be code to call them in .phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); 
?>
```

> Clear cache and reload your browser.