# Cart Page Widget Location

Tags: magento-1.9, widgets

On the cart page I'd like to fill the large white space with the widgets highlighted.

I currently have them put into the page with a Widget set to the main content area.

Is there an easy was to rearrange this?
[image: Widget Location]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the widget from the Admin panel and added the following into `cart.phtml`

`<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('cart_extra_information')->toHtml();?>`

My cart code looked like this below the product table

```
<div class="col2-set">
        <div class="col-1">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('crosssell') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('cart_extra_information')->toHtml();?> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <?php if ($_cartConfig['show_coupon'] || $_cartConfig['show_coupon'] == ''):?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (!$this->getIsVirtual() && $_cartConfig['show_estimate'] || $_cartConfig['show_estimate'] == ''): echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping'); endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And I added some CSS to edit the width of the `.col-1` in the block so I can change that as I want without having to go into the code.

Done with help from this question: [call static block in view.phtml insted of phtml file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113253/call-static-block-in-view-phtml-insted-of-phtml-file)