# Button click to show custom static block in popup in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, cms-pages, popup

I have a custom static block and on my CMS page, I have a button, when the user clicks the button, I need to show the static block in the popup. How can I achieve this in Magento 1.9, can anyone help me?.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="model-body">
        <?php
            echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); 
        ?>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
    btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Replace or add "myBtn" as id to your button

Also put this css too

```
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

For More please follow this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) for popup and this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113253/call-static-block-in-view-phtml-insted-of-phtml-file) for static block part